# How to change the size of toolbars in Windows 7's taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Look at the capture, there are some space between my "Quick Launch" toolbar and the application icons.

[image: pic1]

And I cannot drag the icons upper.

[image: pic2]

I feel the space wastes my total space of taskbar. Do you have any methods to change the size/padding/margin of my "Quick Launch" toolbar?

Comment: See if [this](http://superuser.com/a/498669/138343) helps.

Comment: The tool doesn't work for a vertical taskbar. It cannot reduce vertical space.

Comment: Then I doubt it can be done, but if you find something don't forget to post it as an answer.